# OO Design Advice - Requirements have changed so how to refactor current classes?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, mvvm

A recent new requirement has been presented and I am wondering what would be recommended.

My current design looks somewhat like this:
Presentation Layer: View-ViewModel-Model
Service Layer: WCF (classes generated from ORM classes)
Server Model Layer: ORM-generated classes from DB
Data Store: Relational Database

Everything works fine but now I have to implement a feature that I am wondering if I have to redo my design.  Here's the scenario: I have an Employee table that the ORM generates into the Employee class, which in turn is mapped to the client-side layer (Model) as another Employee class that utilizes WCF to send back to the server via an EmployeeViewModel (it loads the data from the service for that entity (Employee) and other relevant data like drop-down lists via collections of other classes) and this EmployeeViewModel is in turn binds to the EmployeeView.

My Employee class is typical, e.g.

```
public partial class Employee: ViewEntity
{
    // other properties e.g. FirstName, etc.
    [Required]
    public string? Address
    {
        get 
        { 
            return ADDRESS; 
        }
        set
        {
            Validate(value, "Address");
            ADDRESS = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }

    // Other methods...
    public static Employee CreateEmployee(IService service, string firstName, string lastName, string? address)
    {
        var emp = new Employee()
        {
            FIRST_NAME = firstName,
            LAST_NAME = lastName,
            ADDRESS = address
        };
        service.Create(emp);
        return emp;
    }
}
```

The initial requirement was that when the User entered data into the form (EmployeeView), the only required fields were FirstName, LastName, and Address.  In the DB, the FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME are NOT NULLABLE and ADDRESS is NULLABLE.  So the classes abide by this DB design and thus the Address/ADDRESS properties are of type Nullable (string?), but as you can see from my Client's Model, I decorated the Address property with a [Required] annotation and that seemed to suffice the requirement.

But now, I have a new requirement where the User is able to pick one of two values from a drop-down list and depending on the value they pick, the Address is either mandatory or not mandatory.

Ideally, I would like to use all of the same classes, but not sure how to incorporate this new requirement into the above framework.  Do I have to create a new Employee class at the ORM level that inherits from Employee base type, e.g. EmployeeWithAddress, and then have that new class trickle through my Service and ViewModel?  Or maybe create new ViewModels and Views?

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the validation differs between MVC and WCF, but you may look at creating a custom validator.  MVC uses the  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations for validation. If that applies to WCF, you can try it.

Here is an [article](http://favcode.net/browse/condition_validation_with_custom_validationattribute_using_.net_4.0_data_annotations_in_mvc3) I used to get similar functionality in my MVC3 project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I don't believe this is what I'm looking for.  I don't see how that attribute could help in my case, maybe just not seeing it.

Comment: You can create an attribute that, like 'Required' is 'RequiredIf'. So in your case, you have a dropdown that determines if your Address is required. Let's say you store that dropdown value in a property called, Country. If the Country value is 'USA', then address is required. Your decorator for your Address property be [RequiredIf("Country", "USA", ErrorMessage="Address is required if living in the U.S."]